# Userform loops in seemingly reverse order

Tags: excel, vba, loops, userform

I have a userform of 7 checkboxes and some labels that describe them. For each corresponding checkbox there is an array from which there will be created a report if the checkbox is checked as true. However, it doesn't loop through correctly.

I want it to loop through as `A, B, C, D, E, F, G` for for each checkbox who have the `TabIndex` numbers of `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` respectively. However it loops through in the order of `0,6,5,4,3,2,1`.

I have a main sub that defines and declares variables. My userform print code is as follows:

```
Sub Get_PDF_Click()
' Creating PDF

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

PDFUserForm.Hide
i = 0
j = 0
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
        If ctl.Value = True Then
            j = j + 1
            Name_of_File = Array(i + 1, 1) & " report" & YYMM & ".xlsx"
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=OutputPath & Name_of_File
            Set Wkb = Workbooks(Name_of_File)
                For Each ws In Wkb.Worksheets
                    PDF_Name = Array(i + 1, 1) & " " & ws.Name & " " & YYMM
                    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                    OutputPath & PDF_Name, Quality _
                    :=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
                    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
                Next ws
            Wkb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If ' See if checked
    i = i + 1
    Debug.Print ctl.Name
    End If ' See if checkbox
Next ctl

If j > 0 Then
    ' Notification on process time
    SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 0)
    MsgBox "PDF succesfully published after " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds." & Chr(10) & "Location: " & OutputPath, vbInformation
Else
    MsgBox "No file was selected.", vbInformation
End If

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

As an aside I have a similar problem in another piece of code where I loop through charts on a worksheet which is also looping in the wrong order, so perhaps the same solution concept can be applied to that.

Comment: `PDF_Name = Array(i + 1, 1) & ...` strikes me as a recipe for a *type mismatch* error: why make an array with two elements (`i + 1` and `1`) and then try to concatenate that array (??) with a string?

Comment: My array is actually called something else, but I translated it as not to confuse. I realise I failed in doing that. The array contains the name costumers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`For Each` isn't specified to guarantee an enumeration order. In all likelihood the controls are being enumerated *in the order they were added* to the `Me.Controls` collection.

If you need a specific order, use a `For` loop:

```
Dim checkboxNames As Variant
checkboxNames = Array("chkA", "chkB", "chkC", "chkD", "chkE", ...)

Dim current As Long, checkboxName As String, currentBox As MSForms.CheckBox
For current = LBound(checkboxNames) To UBound(checkboxNames)
    checkboxName = checkboxNames(current)
    Set currentBox = Me.Controls(checkboxName)
    'work with the currentBox here
Next
```

Note that this also removes the need to iterate controls you're not interested in

Comment: Thank you worked like a charm. Also, thank you for specifying the enumeration mechanic.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way ;) This does not need you to hard code the name of the checkboxes.

**Logic**: Create a 2D array. Store `Tabindex` and `CheckBox` Name in the array. Sort it on `Tabindex` and use it as you want it :)

**Code**:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Sample()
    Dim CbArray() As String
    Dim n As Long: n = 1
    Dim cbCount As Long
    Dim tindex As String, ctlname As String
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
           n = n + 1
        End If
    Next

    n = n - 1: cbCount = n

    ReDim CbArray(1 To n, 1 To 2)

    n = 1

    '~~> Sort the Tabindex and checkbox name in the array
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
           CbArray(n, 1) = ctl.TabIndex
           CbArray(n, 2) = ctl.Name
           n = n + 1
        End If
    Next

    '~~> Sort the array
    For i = 1 To cbCount
        For j = i + 1 To cbCount
            If CbArray(i, 1) < CbArray(j, 1) Then
                tindex = CbArray(j, 1)
                ctlname = CbArray(j, 2)

                CbArray(j, 1) = CbArray(i, 1)
                CbArray(j, 2) = CbArray(i, 2)

                CbArray(i, 1) = tindex
                CbArray(i, 2) = ctlname
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    '~~> Loop through the checkboxes
    For i = cbCount To 1 Step -1
        With Controls(CbArray(i, 2))
            Debug.Print .Name
            '
            '~~> Do what you want
            '
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you kindly. I look forward to implement this next time I have the chance as it is more dynamic in it's approach and requires less manual updating from my part in the future.